# Default .toggle() easing animation in jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide sidebars by using toggle() jquery function.

Code:

```
$('#hide_saved_templates').click(function(){
        $('#saved_templates').toggle('slow');
        var jobWrapper = $('#job_form_wrapper');

        if(jobWrapper.hasClass('col-md-7'))
        {
            jobWrapper.removeClass('col-md-7');
            $('#hide_saved_templates').removeClass('glyphicon-backward');
            $('#hide_saved_templates').addClass('glyphicon-forward');
            jobWrapper.addClass('col-md-9');
        }
        else if(jobWrapper.hasClass('col-md-10'))
        {
            jobWrapper.removeClass('col-md-10');
            $('#hide_saved_templates').removeClass('glyphicon-backward');
            $('#hide_saved_templates').addClass('glyphicon-forward');
            jobWrapper.addClass('col-md-12');
        }
        else if(jobWrapper.hasClass('col-md-12')){
            jobWrapper.removeClass('col-md-12');
            $('#hide_saved_templates').removeClass('glyphicon-forward');
            $('#hide_saved_templates').addClass('glyphicon-backward');
            jobWrapper.addClass('col-md-10');
        }
        else {
            jobWrapper.removeClass('col-md-9');
            $('#hide_saved_templates').removeClass('glyphicon-forward');
            $('#hide_saved_templates').addClass('glyphicon-backward');
            jobWrapper.addClass('col-md-7');
        }
   });

   $('#hide_job_history').click(function(){
        $('#jobs_history').toggle('slow');
        var jobWrapper = $('#job_form_wrapper');

        if(jobWrapper.hasClass('col-md-7'))
        {
            jobWrapper.removeClass('col-md-7');
            $('#hide_job_history').removeClass('glyphicon-forward');
            $('#hide_job_history').addClass('glyphicon-backward');
            jobWrapper.addClass('col-md-10');
        }
        else if(jobWrapper.hasClass('col-md-10'))
        {
            jobWrapper.removeClass('col-md-10');
            $('#hide_job_history').removeClass('glyphicon-backward');
            $('#hide_job_history').addClass('glyphicon-forward');
            jobWrapper.addClass('col-md-7');
        }
        else if(jobWrapper.hasClass('col-md-9')){
            jobWrapper.removeClass('col-md-9');
            $('#hide_job_history').removeClass('glyphicon-forward');
            $('#hide_job_history').addClass('glyphicon-backward');
            jobWrapper.addClass('col-md-12');
        }
        else if(jobWrapper.hasClass('col-md-12')){
            jobWrapper.removeClass('col-md-12');
            $('#hide_job_history').removeClass('glyphicon-backward');
            $('#hide_job_history').addClass('glyphicon-forward');
            jobWrapper.addClass('col-md-9');
        }

   });
```

The toggle is working fine and toggling the sidebars as expected. However, the default easing animation of toggle('slow') is working perfectly for one sidebar `$('#saved_templates').toggle('slow')` and not working for the other `$('#jobs_history').toggle('slow');` . I have used the same code for both sidebars but I didn't able to understand the reason for this inconsistency. I want to apply smooth simple transition to the toggle effect.

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 no-padding show-templates-outer-wrapper" id="saved_templates" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="no-padding col-md-12" id="job_form_wrapper">
      <span id="hide_saved_templates" class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward" style="cursor: pointer;"></span>
      <span id="hide_job_history" style="position: absolute; right: 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 no-padding show-jobs-history-outer-wrapper" id="jobs_history" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Any errors shown? Can you post part of HTML code?

Comment: @JanRydrych I have added the HTML strucure

Comment: @NuttyProgrammer where is this line `$('#show-jobs-history-outer-wrapper').toggle('slow');` in your code?

Comment: @JohnR sorry, mistype it. Its `$('#jobs_history').toggle('slow');`

Comment: My guess is that it's due to changing the classes for columns at the same time. Toggle will open/close stuff but changing the classes also affects the styling. It's hard to test without the CSS and data to go with it.

Comment: @Rubicksman yup, I am also thinking in the same direction. Does the delay function be useful to run the stuff step-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `toggle` and changing class occurs same time. Since `jobs_history` `div` is in the last position it's `toggle` event is not affecting others. Following code snippet may help you.

```js
var saved_templates = $('#saved_templates');
var jobs_history = $('#jobs_history');

$('#hide_saved_templates').click(function() {
  if (saved_templates.is(':visible')) {
    saved_templates.hide('slow', function() {
      jobs_history.show();
    });
  } else {
    jobs_history.hide();
    saved_templates.show('slow');
  }

  $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-backward glyphicon-forward');
});

$('#hide_job_history').click(function() {
  if (jobs_history.is(':visible')) {
    jobs_history.hide();
    saved_templates.show('slow');
  } else {
    saved_templates.hide('slow', function() {
      jobs_history.show();
    });
  }

  $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-backward glyphicon-forward');
});
```

```css
#saved_templates, #jobs_history, #job_form_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 no-padding show-templates-outer-wrapper" id="saved_templates" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="no-padding col-md-10" id="job_form_wrapper">
    <span id="hide_saved_templates" class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward" style="cursor: pointer;"></span>
    <span id="hide_job_history" style="position: absolute; right: 5px; cursor: pointer;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 no-padding show-jobs-history-outer-wrapper" id="jobs_history" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

See the result in full page.